# Cancel NSOperation From NSOperationQueue

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmanagedobject, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have downloaded information from an url, and I am sending this url as NSOperation in an NSOperationQueue, I want to know, how I can delete a specific NSOperation to download data for a specific url, now I am doing in this way:

```
AppDelegate *appController = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    for (NSOperation *op in appController.seriesQueue.operations) {

        if ([op isKindOfClass:[MyDowndload class]]) {

            MyDownload *urlInDownload = (MyDowndload *)op;

            if ([urlInDownload.myNew.urlName isEqualToString:[managedObject valueForKey:@"urlName"]] && [urlInDownload.myNew.language isEqualToString:[managedObject valueForKey:@"language"]]) {
                [op cancel];
            }
        }
    }
```

I have the information in a tableview, so when I delete a row for index path I enter in this check, and enter also in the [op cancel] line, but I can see in the console log that the thread is still downloading, how can I stop and delete it?

Comment: `url.myNew.language` in if condition. Is it right? or `urlInDownload.myNew.language`?

Comment: i correct, it's only a error paste here, but in my code i write it right...you know i can solve the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to apple guideline, Canceling an operation does not immediately force it to stop what it is doing. Although respecting the value returned by the isCancelled is expected of all operations, your code must explicitly check the value returned by this method and abort as needed.

Example as Justin Suggested....This is way abort execution of method as needed.

```
- (void)main
 { \\ ...do work... 
   if (self.isCancelled)
      { \\ ...get out...  } 
 }
```

[NSOperation Class Reference by apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: +1 a quick example would be useful: MONOperation -- `- (void)main { \n ...do work... \n if (self.isCancelled) { \n ...get out... \n } \n ... \n } \n`.

Comment: thanks, i put some self.isCancelled flag in the NSOperation to check some time in the download, and now works :)

Comment: there is a way to pause all operation in the queue?

Comment: but in this way, i cancel or i pause?

Comment: Cancels all queued and executing operations.

Answer (score 0):

To stop downloading the request operation u need to kill/stop the runloop of that request.

To find the specific operaton in operation queue I think the above operation is the simple one allowed.

if you need more control,

create a subclass of nsoperation and use tag for each operation so that you can find specific operation quickly by checking with unique tag.

And put a custom KVO in the subclass of operation to quiet the operation immediately when needed. 
I mean override the start method of that thread.

thanks,

Naveen Shan

Comment: i have subclassed the nsoperation, MyDownload class is a subclass of NSOperation, and all work right, when i try to cancel it i enter in the if statement, and do the [op cancel]; but don't work...and the url name is a property of that nsoperation subclass that i use for the tag...

Comment: integer checking is faster than string comparison. just override the cancel method and try to stop the runloop.

Comment: making using this KVO, [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isCancelled"];
_isCancelled = YES;
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isCancelled"];